# i got error when installing expo-cli using command npm install --global expo-cli of nodejs Version: 16.14.2

Tags: react-native, expo

that error gives me error when i install react-native
even though i used the command npm audit fix it still not working
I skip and continue, the code still runs but when I turn it off for a while and when I turn it back on it gives me an error and doesn't work

```
C:\Users\Tran Long> npm install --global expo-cli


added 4 packages, changed 1549 packages, and audited 1554 packages in 1m

115 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

24 vulnerabilities (11 moderate, 13 high)


C:\Users\Tran Long>npm audit fix

up to date, audited 1 package in 742ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\Tran Long\Donation>npm install react-native-paper

added 19 packages, and audited 904 packages in 8s

29 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 high severity vulnerabilities

C:\Users\Tran Long\Donation>npm audit fix

up to date, audited 904 packages in 4s

29 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

node-fetch  <=2.6.6
Severity: high
node-fetch is vulnerable to Exposure of Sensitive Information to an Unauthorized Actor - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-r683-j2x4-v87g
The `size` option isn't honored after following a redirect in node-fetch - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w7rc-rwvf-8q5r
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@1.0.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/node-fetch
  isomorphic-fetch  2.0.0 - 2.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
  node_modules/isomorphic-fetch
    fbjs  0.7.0 - 1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of isomorphic-fetch
    node_modules/fbjs
      fbemitter  2.0.3 - 3.0.0-alpha.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
      node_modules/fbemitter
        expo  >=14.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of fbemitter
        node_modules/expo

5 high severity vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue as well

Comment: you can try running node's install additional tools for node.js and should use yarn web instead of expo